# Synonym of もちろん?

Tags: translation, spoken-language, anime, spelling, archaic-language

In *Fruits Basket* S2E5, around 20:30, Hanajima says something that sounds like "**mochi atabou yo**", which is subbed as "**of course**". I guess from this and her character that it's probably some archaic form of **勿論**, but I've just started learning Japanese and don't really know how to look that up, besides searching for couple of ways I imagine it could be spelled (found nothing).

1. Can anyone tell me what it is she actually says?
2. How should I go about looking up something like this in general?

Comment: For those keen on pronunciation, the pitch accent is "high-low" for this もち and "low-high" for the rice cake もち.

Comment: Don't forget to consider looking up slang when trying to determine the origin of a word!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your transcription is correct: もちあたぼうよ

It is divided as

- [もち](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%82%E3%81%A1/#jn-219250) - a contraction of もちろん
- [あたぼう](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%82%E3%81%9F%E3%81%BC%E3%81%86/#jn-4581) - a slangy version of あたりまえ
- [よ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%88/#jn-226011) - a particle.

Regarding よ, I'm not really sure which definition applies, but it may be 語調を整えたり、強めたりする意を表す. Essentially it does not affect the meaning.

On your question of *how*, colloquial expressions are often not covered in Japanese-English dictionaries, so it may be necessary to consult decently large Japanese dictionaries.